# How to execute a JavaScript code in pdf iTextSharp using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, highcharts

I have been working on a MVC Application ASP.NET (C#), in Visual Studio 2012. I would like to use a Highchart chart in my pdf document that I created using iTextSharp (c#). For the Highchart chart I have used some JavaScript code. I want to execute this JavaScript code and include it in my pdf (iTextSharp) document.The code that I have used in c# is:

```
        StringBuilder example_html3 = new StringBuilder();


        example_html3.Append(@"Highcharts.chart(""container"", {");
        example_html3.Append(@"chart: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    type: ""boxplot""");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"title: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    text: ""All Patients""");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"legend: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    enabled: false");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"xAxis: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"categories: [""Asia Pacific"", ""Europe"", ""Latin Am"", ""North Am"", ""SWAC""],");
        example_html3.Append(@"title: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    text: ""      """);
        example_html3.Append(@"}");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"yAxis: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"title: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    text: ""Annual Center Volume 2016""");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"min: 0");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"series: [{");
        example_html3.Append(@"name: ""Region Runs"",");
        example_html3.Append(@"data: [");
        example_html3.Append(@"[1, 4, 18, 43, 74], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[1, 9, 16.5, 32, 62], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[1, 3, 6, 11.5, 22], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[1, 9, 20, 38, 81], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[1, 2, 8, 16, 23]");
        example_html3.Append(@"],");
        example_html3.Append(@"tooltip: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"headerFormat: ""<em>Experiment No {point.key}</em><br/>""");
        example_html3.Append(@"}");
        example_html3.Append(@"}, {");
        example_html3.Append(@"name: ""Outlier"",");
        example_html3.Append(@"color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],");
        example_html3.Append(@"type: ""scatter"",");
        example_html3.Append(@"data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category");
        example_html3.Append(@"[0, 128], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[1, 161], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[2, 58], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[3, 204], ");
        example_html3.Append(@"[4,42] ");
        example_html3.Append(@"],");
        example_html3.Append(@"marker: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    fillColor: ""white"",");
        example_html3.Append(@"    lineWidth: 1,");
        example_html3.Append(@"    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] ");
        example_html3.Append(@"},");
        example_html3.Append(@"tooltip: {");
        example_html3.Append(@"    pointFormat: ""Observation: {point.y}""");
        example_html3.Append(@"}");
        example_html3.Append(@"}]");
        example_html3.Append(@"})");

        string example_html31 = example_html3.ToString();
        PdfAction jaction = PdfAction.JavaScript(example_html31, writer);
        writer.AddJavaScript(jaction);
```

But, my pdf doesn't show the chart. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: iText supports a certain subset of static XML but it does not execute JavaScript. Thus, you need some other component which loads your HTML, executes the JavaScript code, and then allows the retrieval of the finished chart. I'm not sure, though, whether the HTML generated by HighChart is supported by iText.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for your interest and help.